How to transform Mmm dd, yyyy character format to dd-mm-yyyy date format
I tried importing date column into R and this was automatically formated to "Mmm dd, yyyy" (e.g. Feb 21, 2020).
Can you please advise how may I transform it to dd-mm-yyyy format, so that it would be visible as Date (not char anymore).
When I applied
DF$new_date<- as.Date(DF$Date, "%b %d %Y")

I received a vector of NAs...
Can you please advise how to do it?
I tried several methods, none works...
Thank you in advance for help!
Ursula
DF$new_date<- as.Date(DF$Date, "%b %d %Y")

In R date objects are always printed using the ISO_8601 standard. The format argument of as.Date is for reading the right date positions. The way it is printed can be changed with e.g. base R format.Date
mydate <- as.Date("Feb 21, 2020", format = "%b %d, %Y")

format.Date(mydate, format = "%d %m %Y")
[1] "21 02 2020"

but the class changes to character, so it should only be used when printing or plotting and the original data should stay Date.

The answer is technically not correct. The storage mode of Date object is double as it stores fractional days since the "epoch" of 1970-01-01.  The default format for printed dates is indeed yyyy-mm-dd aka ISO 8601.  Now, to get a character representation of a date to be a Date object, it needs to be parsed, and for that you need a format (and usually a few common forms are tried).

You need to include the comma in your format specification, as in this example
as.Date(c("Feb 21, 2020", "Feb 3, 2021"), "%b %d, %Y")
[1] "2020-02-21" "2021-02-03"

The output of as.Date() will be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. Is there any reason you can't use that?
